# how to fix hb-ft.h no such file or directory while installing pango using jhbuild?

Tags: freetype, pango, jhbuild, harfbuzz

i have all the dependencies and since i was not able to fix this error i installed freetype and harfbuzz from scratch still couldnt fix this fatal error but this file (hb-ft.h) is present under 
/usr/include/harfbuzz/hb-ft.h and
jhbuild/checkout/harfbuzz/src/hb-ft.h

```
In file included from pango-ot-buffer.c:24:0:
pango-ot-private.h:29:19: fatal error: hb-ft.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:1387: recipe for target 'pango-ot-buffer.lo' failed
make[4]: *** [pango-ot-buffer.lo] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
pangofc-shape.c:30:19: fatal error: hb-ft.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:1387: recipe for target 'pangofc-shape.lo' failed
make[4]: *** [pangofc-shape.lo] Error 1
pangoft2-render.c: In function ‘pango_ft2_font_render_glyph’:
pangoft2-render.c:224:3: warning: ‘pango_ft2_font_get_face’ is deprecated: Use 'pango_fc_font_lock_face' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   face = pango_ft2_font_get_face (font);
   ^
In file included from pangoft2-private.h:26:0,
                 from pangoft2-render.c:37:
../pango/pangoft2.h:125:9: note: declared here
 FT_Face        pango_ft2_font_get_face     (PangoFont       *font);
         ^
In file included from pango-ot-info.c:34:0:
pango-ot-private.h:29:19: fatal error: hb-ft.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:1387: recipe for target 'pango-ot-info.lo' failed
make[4]: *** [pango-ot-info.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/onkar0027/jhbuild/checkout/pango/pango'
Makefile:1469: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/onkar0027/jhbuild/checkout/pango/pango'
Makefile:1212: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/onkar0027/jhbuild/checkout/pango/pango'
Makefile:579: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/onkar0027/jhbuild/checkout/pango'
Makefile:468: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
*** Error during phase build of pango: ########## Error running make -j 5  *** [7/7]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen this error before while building pango in jhbuild.

**Solution**:
Open a new terminal and try -

```
jhbuild buildone -afc harfbuzz
```

After it's successfully build, rerun phase build of the pango module.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Omg finally, please can you explain me what exactly that command did and why didn't jhbuild build harfbuzz itself

Comment: In my case, jhbuild *had* built harfbuzz, but without FreeType support. I rebuilt FreeType and then rebuilt harfbuzz, but the support still wasn't present. The command in this answer does a more complete job of reconfiguring: `-a` means run autogen.sh, `-f` means force build even if it's already installed, and `-c` means run `make clean` before build step.